# jQuery UI Dialog Modal option not working with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the need to render a jQuery UI dialog when an event occurs on a page.

The dialog has the following settings.

```
var opt = {
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 1000,
    height: 650,
    title: 'Title Here'
};
```

When the button is pressed the following code runs. (Along with 500 other lines)

```
 $("#dlgInfo").dialog(opt).dialog("open");
```

All well and good so far in chrome and Firefox. Except IE doesn't render the dialog at all.
Research suggests that IE is being a little to eager to render the box and fails. 
A solution is to wrap the open code in a setTimeout function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#dlgInfo").dialog(opt).dialog("open");
}, 500);
```

Success, the dialog now opens in all browsers, but for some reason I loose the Model property in chrome. I have no idea why..

EDIT...

I'm beginning to think that an JSON call is messing this up. It looks like the Modal option is being set but when a JSON object renders to the page it causes the modal aspect to vanish.

Here is an example of the JSON code.

```
$('#clientResults').empty();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + "handlers/clients.ashx?" + $("#searchfield").val(),
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    $('#clientResults').append('<a id="Clients"><h1>Clients (' + data.Clients.length + ') - Click client name to view client matters.</h1></a>');
    if (data.Clients.length > 0) {
        $('#clientResults').append('<table id="clientTable" class="Results clients"><thead><tr><th>Group Entity</th><th>Client Name</th><th>Client Code</th><th>Status</th><th>Type</th><th>Office</th><th>Active</th><th>Responsible Billing Partner</th><th>Open Date</th><th>Close Date</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
         for (var i = data.Clients.length; i--;) {
             $('#clientTable > tbody:last').append('<tr id = "' + data.Clients[i].Group + $.trim(data.Clients[i].ClientCode) + '" onclick="addDetails(this.rowIndex);"><td>' + data.Clients[i].Group + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].ClientName + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].ClientCode + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].Status + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].entity_type + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].Office + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].Active + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].RespBillEmpl + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].OpenDate + '</td><td>' + data.Clients[i].CloseDate + '</td></tr>');
                }
               $("#clientTable").tablesorter();
            }
        },
        failure: function () {
            $('#clientResults').empty();
            $('#clientResults').append('<a id="Clients"><h1>Clients</h1></a>');
            $('#clientResults').append('An error has occoured getting the client data. Please contact Service Desk on ext 5555. Thanks');
        }
    });
```

`#ClientResults` is an empty div tag.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a chaining issue. Can you try splitting it into two statements like this?

```
$("#dlgInfo").dialog(opt);
$("#dlgInfo").dialog("open");
```

If that didn't work then maybe this?

```
$("#dlgInfo").dialog(opt);

setTimeout(function(){

    $("#dlgInfo").dialog("open");

}, 1);
```

It could also be a scope issue. Do you get the expected results if you log the `opt` object?

```
console.log(opt);
$("#dlgInfo").dialog(opt);
$("#dlgInfo").dialog("open");
```

Comment: Interesting... I say that because all the other properties of opt work. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I found your symptoms to be quite weird as well. Any luck with this?